# Find a value in a table row, and if it is there, update it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to find a person in my table and update their score. This is the code I have right now. For some reason it's not working. Instead of changing the person's score, it will just make a new row with the same name of the person.

```
$name = $_POST["strtolower(name)"];
$team = $_POST["team"];
$num = $_POST["number"];
$goals = $_POST["goals"];

if($query = mysqli_query("SELECT goals FROM goalscorers WHERE name=$name ", $db)){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $origgoals = $row['goals'];
    $newgoals = (int)$origgoals + (int)$goals;
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE goalscorers SET goals=$newgoals WHERE name=$name ");
    echo "<h1>Thank you for submitting your details! <br /> <a href=\"goalscorers.php\">Add another</a></h1>";
  }
  mysqli_free_result($query);
}
else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO goalscorers (name, team, num, goals) VALUES ('$name','$team','$num','$goals') ";
    $result = mysqli_query($query, $db);
    if (mysqli_error()) { print "Database ERROR: " . mysql_error(); } 

    echo "<h1>Thank you for submitting your details! <br /> <a href=\"goalscorers.php\">Add another</a></h1>";
}
```

I'm very new to both PHP and MySQL so it's probably a basic mistake.

Also, I already am connected to the database.

Comment: I don't know who told you to use mysqli that way, but don't.

Comment: MySQL has the option to update on duplicate primary keys: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html This would let you have just the insert statement with the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you don't have quotes around string values in your sql queries. Change

```
"SELECT goals FROM goalscorers WHERE name=$name "
```

to

```
"SELECT goals FROM goalscorers WHERE name = '$name'"
                                            ^     ^
```

and

```
"UPDATE goalscorers SET goals=$newgoals WHERE name=$name "
```

to

```
"UPDATE goalscorers SET goals=$newgoals WHERE name = '$name'"
                                                     ^     ^
```

***On a side note:** learn and use [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ). Your code is vulnerable to sql injections.*

---

**UPDATE1:** You can drastically simplify your code with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. In order for it to work properly you have to have a UNIQUE (PRIMARY KEY) index on `name` column.
Your insert statement then should look like

```sql
INSERT INTO goalscorers (`name`, `team`, `num`, `goals`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE goals = goals + VALUES(goals)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4efeb)** demo

---

**UPDATE2:** Now your code with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and prepared statement can look like this

```
$name  = $_POST['name'];
$team  = $_POST['team'];
$num   = $_POST['number'];
$goals = $_POST['goals'];

/* connect to the database*/
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'userpwd', 'test');
/* check connection */
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Connection failed: ' .$db->connect_error);
}

$sql = 'INSERT INTO goalscorers (`name`, `team`, `num`, `goals`)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE goals = goals + VALUES(goals)';
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $db->prepare($sql)) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("ssii", $name, $team, $num, $goals);
    /* execute query */
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo '<h1>Thank you for submitting your details! <br /> <a href="goalscorers.php">Add another</a></h1>';
    } else {
        die('Insert failed: ' .$db->error);    
    }
    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    die('Statement prepare failed: ' .$db->error);    
}
```

Comment: The changes need to be a little more extensive than that.

Comment: @blubex You're welcome :) Please take a look at updated answer and consider to switch using prepared statements.